# SynchronizationLockException in AsyncSeq.cache

Tags: .net, f#, async-await

When I call AsyncSeq.cache I get SynchronizationLockException at the line calling Monitor.Exit(iref). Can anybody say what the problem is?

Please note that I'm using AsyncSeq.cache in another project without such problems.

Thanks!

See below my test code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let asyncOp x =
        async {
            do! Async.Sleep x
            return x
        }

    let chooser x = if x > 1000 then Some x else None

    let execute (input : AsyncSeq<int>) =
        async {
            printfn "First result... Expect 3s sleep"
            let! r1 = AsyncSeq.tryPick chooser input
            printfn "Computing second result. Expect no sleep"
            let! r2 = AsyncSeq.tryPick chooser input
            printfn "Done"
            return (r1,r2)
        }

    printfn "Starting..."

    let v =
        [1000;2000;3000;300000]
        |> AsyncSeq.ofSeq
        |> AsyncSeq.mapAsync asyncOp
        |> AsyncSeq.cache
        |> execute
        |> Async.RunSynchronously


    printfn "results: = %A" v
    do System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

See below the code for AsyncSeq.cache for reference

```
let cache (source : AsyncSeq<'T>) = 
    let cache = ResizeArray<_>()
    asyncSeq {
        use ie = source.GetEnumerator() 
        let iRef = ref 0
        let fin = ref false
        while not fin.Value do
            let i = iRef.Value
            lock(iRef)
            let lockTaken = ref false
            try 
                System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(iRef, lockTaken);
                if i >= cache.Count then 
                    let! move = ie.MoveNext()
                    cache.Add(move)
                    iRef := i + 1
            finally
                if lockTaken.Value then
                    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(iRef)
            match cache.[i] with 
            | Some v -> yield v
            | None -> fin := true }
```

Comment: Not familiar with F# but you can't use both async and a `Monitor` since `Monitor` is thread-affine (i.e. only the thread that entered can exit) while async doesn't necessarily use the same thread.

Comment: Well, this is the implementation of cache that I found here: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/blob/master/src/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/AsyncSeq.fs Does this mean the implementation is broken?

Comment: @vidi yes it probably is a bug - please file an issue right there

Comment: I filed an issue at AsyncSeq project https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/issues/33